# Are the rear burners of my gas stove interconnected?

Tags: stove

I have a gas stove when I light the back burners together they light up if I turn off one the other after a few seconds goes out and if I try to light only one at a time the fire 'e does not hold and the thermocouple turns off the gas is my gas cooker faulty?

Comment: I would think faulty.  Each burner should work independent of each other.  Most people do not want roasted arm when stirring a pot.

Comment: Has the stove always been like this or are these symptoms new?

Comment: It's a ew stove

Comment: Seems a bit like the back burner thermocouples might be mixed up. If they're both on them they're both happy. But if only one is on then it gets shut off by it's partner.

Comment: This question has been sitting around for a while, which is to be expected because it is [on the back burner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/on-the-back-burner)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the symptoms you're describing, it does seem like there might be an issue with your gas stove, specifically with the thermocouple system. The thermocouple is a safety device that detects whether the burner is lit by sensing the heat from the flame. If it doesn't detect a flame, it shuts off the gas to prevent a leak.

In a normally functioning stove, each burner should operate independently, so it's unusual that turning off one burner causes the other one to go out, or that you can't light just one burner at a time.

Here are a few possibilities:

1. **Faulty Thermocouples**: If the thermocouples for your rear burners are faulty or misaligned, they might not be effectively sensing the heat from the flames, causing them to shut off the gas prematurely.
2. **Gas Supply Issue**: There could be an issue with the gas supply to the burners. If the gas pressure is too low, there might not be enough gas reaching the burners for the flames to stay lit.
3. **Burner Cap Misalignment or Clogging**: If the burner caps are misaligned or the burners are clogged, it can prevent the gas from flowing properly, which can extinguish the flame.

Given the potential risks associated with gas appliances, if you're experiencing these issues, it would be safest to stop using the affected burners and consult with a professional appliance repair service. They can properly diagnose and fix the issue to ensure your stove is safe to use.